Topology of a horocycle
In hyperbolic plane there is some length scale $\ell$. There exist three types of curves of constant curvature on this plane: exocycles (curvature $<\ell^{-1}$), horocycles (curvature $=\ell^{-1}$) and circles (curvature $>\ell^{-1}$).
I believe that quite evidently exocycles have topolgy $\mathbb{R}$ and circles have topology $\mathbb{S}_1$.
What is the topology of a horocycle? Is it one of the above cases, or its own category?
P.S.: Eventhough I believe my question should be fine it might be too sloppy, not use proper terminology (blame it on me being physicist, not mathematician) or have other deficiencies. In such case please suggest in which direction should I expand or clarify the question. I did use some google-fu, but not an extensive amount, so also sorry if the answer can be googled rather easily. I failed at that.

A horocycle in the hyperbolic plane $\mathbb H$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$. You can see this in any of the many models of the hyperbolic plane. You can find information about the various models of the hyperbolic plane in most published mathematical textbooks on hyperbolic geometry. I also like this article by Cannon, Floyd, Kenyon, and Parry.
I'll describe horocycles in two models.
Perhaps you know the Poincaré model which is the interior of the unit disc
$$\mathbb D \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid x^2+y^2<1\} \subset \mathbb R^2
$$
with Riemannian metric
$$ds^2 = 4\frac{dx^2+dy^2}{(1 - x^2 - y^2)^2}
$$
Horocycles in the Poincaré model $\mathbb D$ correspond one-to-one with ordinary Euclidean circles $C \subset \mathbb R^2$ such that $C$ is tangent to the unit circle $x^2+y^2=1$ at the point $P$, and such that $C-P$ lies entirely in $\mathbb D$. The horocycle itself, that corresponds to $C$, is $C-P$. Removing one point from a circle leaves a subspace homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$.
And since you mentioned that you are a physicist, perhaps you know the hyperboloid model for $\mathbb H$, which is embedded in $\mathbb R^3$ with $(x,y,t)$ coordinates, and is given by
$$\mathbb H = \{(x,y,t) \mid x^2+y^2-t^2=-1, t>0\}
$$
The metric in this model is the restriction to $\mathbb H$ of the ordinary Minkowski metric $dx^2 + dy^2 - dt^2 = -1$, which when restricted to $\mathbb H$ is positive definite.
Horocycles in this model are all described as follows. Consider a plane $P$ which is parallel to a line in the light cone, and which intersects the $t$-axis at a point where $t>0$. Such a plane can be described by an equation of the form
$$P = \{Ax + By + Ct = 1\}, \quad C=A+B, \quad C>0
$$
With a bit of geometry you might be able to convince yourself that $\mathbb H \cap P$ is homeomorphic to a line, in fact it is an ordinary parabola in the plane $P$. The horocycle itself, that corresponds to $P$, is $\mathbb H \cap P$.  For the special case $P = \{x+t=1\}$, the intersection $\mathbb H \cap P$ is given in $y,t$ coordinates by $(1-t)^2 + y^2 - t^2 = -1$ which simplifies to $t = \frac{1}{2} y^2 + 1$.

[This paragraph was based on a misreading, but I'll leave it here so that comments make sense.] And by the way, the units of curvature are not inverse length, but instead inverse area. One way to remember this is by knowing the Gauss-Bonnet equation, one side of which is a dimensionless surface integral $\iint_S \kappa \, dA$ where $\kappa$ is the curvature. So in the curvature (in)equalities that you wrote in your post, it would be better to write $\ell^{-2}$ rather than $\ell^{-1}$.

Thank you very much, it is very much as I expected, but wanted to make sure geometry has not prepared some nasty surprise to me. I had exactly Poincaré model in mind, but was not sure about the point in the infinity.

Regarding your final note, I probably used a wrong word there, as by curvature one probably understoods smth like extrinsic curvature, right? But on a metric manifold with metric $g$ a 1D curve with unit tangent $t$ I can specify its curvature simply as $c=t\cdot\nabla t$ (nabla is Levi-Civita covariant derivative adapted to $g$), right? Wouldn't $|c| = \sqrt{g(c,c)}$ have units of inverse length, basically corresponding to the inverse radius of a circle with equal curvature tangent to given curve at given point?

I can see now that I misread how you used the word "curvature" in your post. On first reading, I saw "Gaussian curvature", which is the intrinsic curvature of the Riemannian metric itself; if this were, say, a surface in Euclidean space then it would be equal to extrinsic curvature of that surface, which is Gauss' famous Theorema Egregium. But I see now that you did explicitly say curvature of the curves themselves, so I think are right in that case.

I found articles by Soviet mathematicians, roughly 1927-1951, where the OP's view is the starting point; "constant curvature"  curves... I think that was the two by Mordukhai-Boltovskoi in references http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~jagy/papers/Intelligencer_1995.pdf

Prof. Mosher gave a great answer from the geometry point of view; here is a complementary answer from the dynamical point of view:

The unit tangent bundle $UT(\mathbb{H})$ of the upper half plane $\mathbb{H}$ can be identified with the group $PSL(2,\mathbb{R})$ of linear fractional transformations $z\mapsto \dfrac{az+b}{cz+d}$ (modulo $\pm I$) with $ad-bc=1$; it carries three important and natural actions; one the geodesic flow coming from multiplication by diagonal matrices and two horocycle flows (so-called stable and unstable) coming from multiplication by upper or lower triangular matrices.
A horocycle then is the image of an orbit of a horocycle flow under the projection map $UT(\mathbb{H})\to\mathbb{H}$ that takes the initial position and direction information and deletes the initial direction, thus (which thus arguably requires some work) has the topology (and smooth structure) of $\begin{pmatrix}1 & \ast\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\cong\mathbb{R}$.
For more details see Einsiedler & Ward's Ergodic Theory.
